# Simultaneous Recoding and Receiving Data after passing commands through Serial Port

Tags: c#, .net

Case 1

I have designed a Serial Monitor GUI using c# that receives sensor data through the serial port. I have multiple sensors which are arranged in an array format in custom PCB. The data(sample data) is received from the microcontroller in the format every 1 ms.

```
Array_A 1.2,1.4,1.7,1.8
Array_B 1.45,1.56,1.71,1.22
```

I can visualize the sensor data using Charts and simultaneously I am recording the data using DGV. This works perfectly fine.

Case 2

Here my question is, I am going to add a functionality to the GUI to send Commands from GUI to Microcontroller and get the specific sensor data value. If I add this functionality then the data will be sent by the microcontroller will come through the serial port and the code breaks down (Case 1 Fails). As the GUI breaks if any additional line comes through the serial monitor i.e- 3rd line in the data.

```
Array_A 1.2,1.4,1.7,1.8
Array_B 1.45,1.56,1.71,1.22
Poti 1.89
```

How can I implement the same(Case 2) in the GUI? Any suggestions. Thank you.

The code is very big if you want to take a look into it, please click the GitHub link. [Code](https://github.com/PratikhyaManas/Project/tree/master/WindowsFormsTest)

Comment: Figure out which portion of your big code is the smallest possible example code that reproduces your problem, and post it directly into your question here.  For guidance, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Once you've done that, describe your problem in more detail.  Is the UI freezing?  Is the serial port code freezing?  Are you using Winforms or WPF?  Generally speaking, UI programs in Windows are Single-Threaded Apartments; I suspect you need to run your serial port code on a separate thread, and use Invoke to get the data back to your UI.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I am using Winforms App to create the GUI. The code fails in the TimerSerial function in the code as this function handles the Incoming data from Serial Port. Can you please give some suggestions on how to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: Figure out which portion of your big code is the smallest possible example code that reproduces your problem, and post it directly into your question here. For guidance, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I have implemented the same in GUI and it is working properly. But I have a question, I am using 2 Winforms Timer, one for processing the serial data coming from a microcontroller and the other to display on chart and DGV. How can I use the 2nd Timer in thread and speed up my GUI. Please provide any suggestions. I have very little knowledge about threading.

Comment: Learn more about threads.  A Timer is probably not the best way to do this.